# XSLT on XML file with defaultnamespace. Xpath with 'artificial' prefix

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a large database XML file with defaultnamespace to be transformed using XSLT. Here is a minimal example.

The file is called server.xml. It contains incorrect data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore xmlns="http://www.mybook.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <book author="Incorrect_Author">
    <title>Correct_Title</title>  
 </book>
</bookstore>
```

The author needs to be changed to the correct value by matching the title of the book in another XML file.

This second xml file is called client.xml. It contains the correct author name for the book.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore xmlns="http://www.mybook.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <book author="Correct_Author">
    <title>Correct_Title</title>  
    <additionalstuff/>
 </book>
</bookstore>
```

However, it also has additional info I don't want. So I want to modify server based on client, matching by book title.

I have written the following XSLT (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695548/find-and-replace-xml-attribute-values-from-one-file-to-another?lq=1)). It works to do the job if I artificially remove the default xmlns in my xml files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="clientXml" select="'client.xml'" />

<xsl:variable name="client" select="document($clientXml)//book" />

<xsl:template match="book/@author">
    <xsl:attribute name="author">
        <xsl:value-of select="$client[child::title=current()/../title]/@author" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I need this to work with the files as they are (containing the default ns). I know this is a current question, so I have tried the following code based on answers I found. It doesn't work. Is it a problem with the XPath prefixing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:v="http://www.mybook.com" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="v" >

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="clientXml" select="'client.xml'" />

 <xsl:variable name="client" select="document($clientXml)//v:book" />

 <xsl:template match="v:book/@author">
    <xsl:attribute name="author">
        <xsl:value-of select="$client[child::title=current()/../title]/@author" />
    </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

XPaths, including those used in XSLT, are namespace-aware... and unfortunately do not support the concept of a default namespace, at least in the 1.0 version of the specs. To match a namespaced node, you must use a properly bound prefix in your stylesheet's paths even if you didn't do so in the input document.

Comment: Thank you for this precision. My problem was that, even though I knew this theoretically, I could not figure out where to write the prefix in the path command.

Comment: For what it's worth, I *tried* to convince the XPath Working Group to support the pseudo-syntax `{namespaceURI}localname` rather than only supporting namespaces via prefixes or by explicitly testing namespace name and local name individually. They felt it was important to emphasize the use of prefixes in order to get XML Namespaces adopted, and rejected the suggestion. Oh Well.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Prefixing is the correct approach. You just missed prefixing the `title` element selector:

```
<xsl:template match="v:book/@author">
    <xsl:attribute name="status">
        <xsl:value-of select="$client[child::v:title=current()/../v:title]/@author" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Since the namespace in the source is the *default* namespace, that namespace applies to all descendant elements, not only `bookstore` or `book`. In the stylesheet you assign that namespace to a prefix because XPath *requires* that any element selectors in a namespace be *explicitly* prefixed.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works indeed now. Would you have a good reference to the usage of prefixes? I got it wrong initially because I wasn't sure where to add the prefix specification. For example, I was not sure if the @author also needed to specify the prefix. I understood it should not, but it's still a bit mysterious to me.

Comment: The prefix is just a reference to qualify a *name* as being part of a namespace. When a default namespace is declared (`xmlns` without a suffix), it is *inherited* by the *element* where it is declared and *all* of its descendant *elements* (until some descendant overrides it with another  suffixless `xmlns` declaration. Attributes may also be qualified by a namespace, but it has to be done *explicitly* through a prefix. Namespace declarations that map to a prefix also apply to the current element *if it is prefixed* and to all *prefixed* descendant elements and attributes.

Comment: This is a very good reference on XML Namespaces: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx . You can also refer to the [XML Names specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/).

Answer (score 1):

If namespaces are not so significant for your transformation
changing the template:

```
<xsl:template match="book">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name(.)=‘book']">
```

Will make the template work irrespective of its namespace.If you need to handle simple transformations using this might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I don't manage to make it work. I tried the following. Is that what you meant?
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name(.)=‘book']/@author">
        <xsl:attribute name="author">
            <xsl:value-of select="$client[child::title=current()/../title]/@author" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: This is also a valid way to use XPath. Here you are *ignoring* the namespace and dealing only with the *local* part. A name which is part of a namespace (also called a QName, or *qualified* name), has a namespace part and a local part. It is usually *represented* like this: `{http://www.mybook.com}:book`. You can't use such identifiers in XPath or XML, so you either *map* the namespace to a prefix or use it without the prefix if it is mapped automatically to the *default* namespace. When you use `*[local-name()='book']` you are selecting *all* elements which have a local name equal to `book`.

Comment: And ignoring the namespace completely. In your case you would have to apply this not only to `book` but also to all *elements* that are part of a namespace (such as `title`). This is OK when you *know* there will be no conflicts with local names of other namespaces (the local names of `v:book` and some other `book` or `xyz:book` are the same)